# Excel - Find duplicate values in two rows with two conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, duplicate, cells

Could someone guide me to find the correct formula for this case of conditional formatting in Excel?

**1- Highlight the two adjacent cells in orange only if their values are the same on the same line**

**2- Highlight the values in green when they are found in both rows but in different positions**

the expected result should be like the attached image.

I've tried **=A1=B1** with orange color but it seems not working correctly.

Regards.

[image]

Comment: Look at Conditional Formatting. This very scenario is what it is made for

Comment: What if same value occurs at multiple rows elsewhere e.g. say 'sms' in Col A at A5 also occurs at B7 as well as B10? Should all three be highlighted? For row to same row match you can simply use =EXACT(A1,B1) and put desired highlight in Conditional Formatting for both cells and copy the formats down. You need to create a second rule checking for all across probably MATCH function can do the trick.

Comment: @pat2015 values are unique, those are Android XML strings, the aim is to put the same string values in different languages in front each other to facilitate the translation and verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution. In this example data is in rows 1 thru 11 in Columns A & B.
Conditional formatting first rule in A1 & B1

```
=EXACT(A1,B1)
```

Select desired highlight and copy the Formats to all applicable cells i.e. A1 thru B11.

Second rule in A1

```
=MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$11,0)>1
```

select second highlight color and copy the formats from A2 thru A11.

Second rule in B1

```
=MATCH(B1,$A$1:$A$11,0)>1
```

Select the same matching color as from A1 for this second condition. Remember that this must be set as second condition and copy the formats from B2 thru B11.

[image]

Remember that EXACT function used in the first condition is Case Sensitive whereas MATCH used in second condition is not.  =A1=B1 should work provided it is put in both adjacent cells and it's not case sensitive.